# Can't get icon in language menu

Tags: magento2, language

I want to switch my language menu with flags. I am using Fasony theme.
my current code for the language_custom.phtml is :

```
<?php if (count($block->getStores())>1): ?>
<?php $id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : ''?>
<div class="switcher language switcher-language">
    <strong class="label switcher-label hidden"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Language') ?></span></strong>    
    <span class="switcher-title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Your Language : ') ?></span>
    <div class="selected">
        <strong class="view-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentStoreCode()) ?>">
            <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreName()) ?></span>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <ul class="sub-option">
        <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
            <?php if ($_lang->getId() != $block->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
                <li class="view-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()); ?> switcher-option">
                    <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>'>
                        <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-<?php echo $_lang->getCode() ?>"></span> <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and it looks like this : 
[image]

I changed it with this code :

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php if ($_lang->getCode() != 'default'): ?>
        <a class="lang-flag" href="<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl().'?___store='.$_lang->getCode();?>" style="text-decoration:none;" title="<?php echo $_lang->getCode();?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/'.$_lang->getCode().'.gif');?>" alt="<?php echo $_lang->getCode();?>">
        </a>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

But I can't get the pictures :

[image]

in the code inspector I get empty src="":

```
<a class="lang-flag" href="?___store=english" style="text-decoration:none;" title="english">
    <img src="" alt="english">
</a>
```

I want also to change the icon of the setting with the current language flag.

My flag icons english.png and deutsch.png are in the folder : `app/design/frontend/Venustheme/fasony/web/images/flags/`

Answer (score 1):

maybe a little late, but I tried your code changing the url image with this and it worked well :

```
<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/flags/flag_' . $_lang->getCode() . '.gif'));?>
```

as I see you don't use $block but $this, maybe we're not using same version of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Fine, just hide the language in the string, replace:

```
<a class="lang-flag" href="<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl().'?___store='.$_lang->getCode();?>" style="text-decoration:none;" title="<?php echo $_lang->getCode();?>">
```

with:

```
<a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang) ?>'>
```